# Ground state of local parent Hamiltonians and invariance under local unitaries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hamiltonian, unitarity

Assume that a finite-dimensional pure state $|\psi\rangle\in \mathcal{H}\simeq \mathbb{C}^m$, $m<\infty$, is the (unique) frustration-free ground state of a local parent Hamiltonian and suppose that the locality notion is given in terms of a *connected* set of neighbourhoods $\{\mathcal{N}_k\}$. My question is the following one: Is it true that any unitary $U$ satisfying $$U|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|U^\dagger=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$$ can be decomposed into a finite product of invariance-satisfying unitaries acting only on the neighbourhoods $\{\mathcal{N}_k\}$, that is $U$ can be written as $U=\prod_{i=1}^N U_{\mathcal{N}_{k_i}}$, where every $U_{\mathcal{N}_{k_i}}$ acts only on the neighbourhood $\mathcal{N}_{k_i}$ and it is such that $U_{\mathcal{N}_{k_i}}|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|U_{\mathcal{N}_{k_i}}^\dagger=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$
?

Any (partial) answer/comment/reference is very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43639/discussion-on-question-by-jacquard-ground-state-of-local-parent-hamiltonians-and).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't simple **translation symmetry** an example?

E.g. suppose you have a one-dimensional ring of $L$ spins described by $|\psi\rangle = \sum_{\{\sigma_i\}} \psi_{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_L} \; |\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_N\rangle$. Then this wavefunction could be invariant under the unitary transformation $\psi_{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_{L-1},\sigma_L} \to \psi_{\sigma_2,\sigma_3,\cdots,\sigma_L,\sigma_1}$. However you clearly cannot do this locally, unless I misunderstand your characterization.

An even more visceral counter-example would be (spatial) **inversion symmetry**.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the toric code Hamiltonian situated on a spherical geometry. This has a unique ground state. Expand the sphere to an infinite radius. Consider a string excitation of the ground state, and loop the string around the sphere (an infinite number of local operations) such that it meets itself, returning our system to its ground state. We know by analogy to the topologically protected ground states of the toric code on an infinite toroidal geometry that such an evolution is not possible with a finite number of local operations. Thus we have described a unitary evolution of the system, with the ground state as its eigenstate, which can not be expressed as a finite decomposition of local operations.

That being said, I may just be cheating by how I am taking the thermodynamic limit, and you may have to clarify such considerations in your question.

Comment: Cheating it is.

Comment: This is correct. However, I forgot to write in the OP that I'm working on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space (my fault, sorry!).  I edited the OP accordingly.

Comment: No worries, it was helpful for me to formulate this answer anyways.

Comment: This is complete cheating.  If you want to decompose an operation on an infinite system into a product on local operations, it is clear that you need to ask for an infinite number of them. This has nothing to do with the toric code, the same works for a product state.

Comment: You're right Norbert. Somehow I thought I was on the right track, but I should have given this some more careful thought.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea:

Say $U|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$ for $UU^\dagger = U^\dagger U = I$.

Then if we consider the exponential form $U = \exp(iG)$ with $G = G^\dagger$ as usual, $|\psi\rangle$ must necessarily be in the kernel  of $G$, $G|\psi\rangle = 0$.

On the other hand, having $U$ of the product form $U = \prod_k{U_{{\mathcal N}_k} }$ for mutually disjoint neighborhoods is equivalent to $G = \sum_k{G_{{\mathcal N}_k}}$ with $[G_{{\mathcal N}_j}, G_{{\mathcal N}_k}] = 0$ for any ${\mathcal N}_j$, ${\mathcal N}_k$ involved.

But obviously not all $G$ that have $|\psi\rangle$ in their kernel are of this decomposable form. So not all $U$ such that $U|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$ can be of the product type $U = \prod_k{U_{{\mathcal N}_k} }$.

Comment: @Jacquard I think your question is related with the problem of the geometrical structure of quantum states. For a general density matrix $\rho=U_{0}\sigma U_{0}^{+}$, it can be easily verified that the $U$ keeps $\rho$ invariant is given by $U_{0}gU_{0}^{+}$, with $g\sigma=\sigma g$. This is very similar to the Generalized Hopf Fibration of mixed state proposed by Montgomery in "Heisenberg and Isoholonomic Inequalities" and a similar work later in "DYNAMIC DISTANCE MEASURES ON SPACES OF ISOSPECTRAL MIXED QUANTUM STATES".

Comment: So there is no gurantee that the $U$ is something 'local', it really depends on the density matrix of the system $\rho$. For your question concerning only pure states, $g$ can be decomposed into a product as $g=U(1)\otimes U(N-1)$, but considering $U=U_{0}gU_{0}^{+}$, it's still not 'local'.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that $g$ should be unitary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you considering disjoint neighbourhood topologies? If not, why are you decomposing $U$ as the product of local unitaries acting on disjoint neighbourhoods?

Comment: No. Since we have $U=U_{0}gU_{0}^{+}$ which can keep the system state invariant but not $g$, so even $g$ can be decomposed into a form as a product of disjoint operations,  $U$ is not a product of local operators.

Comment: @X.Dong: my comment was related to udrv's answer. Anyway, your comments concern general density matrices, in my case I have the constraint that these are ground states of parent Hamiltonians with a prescribed neighbourhood topology.

Comment: @Jacquard As I mentioned, pure state case is only a special case here, where $U=U_{0}(U(1)\otimes U(N-1))U_{0}^{+}$. So still for pure states, you can not achieve your goal to decompose $U$ as a product of local operators.

Comment: @X.Dong: Okay, If I understood well, $U_0$ can destroy the locality of the decomposition. But if the pure state $|\psi\rangle$ is the ground state of a parent Hamiltonian, we are restricting the set of pure states we are considering. How can we be sure that $U_0$ in this case doesn't exhibit some special structure that preserves locality?

Comment: It really depends how you define the radius of 'neighbourhood'. As seen even $U_{0}$ is special, $g=U(1)\otimes U(N-1)$ can fulfill the requirement and $U_{0}$ is special to keep the product structure, can we say that $U(N-1)$ is 'local'? Anyway it really depends on $\rho$, so there is no general conclusion and we have to give a specific answer for each different $\rho$ (or $U_{0}$).

Comment: @X.Dong: Yes, I agree with you on the fact that the problem heavily depends on the state $\rho$ and on the neighbourhood structure. That's why I'm looking for a counterexample.

Comment: As for counter examples, I think 2 qubit Bell state $00+11$ with $\sigma=Diag(1,0,0,0)$ and $U_{0}=[1,0,0,1; 1,0,0,-1; 0, 1, 0, 0;0,0,1,0]$. Then we see $U=U_{0}*(U(1)\otimes U(3))*U_{0}^{+}$ can not be written as a product of local unitaries.

Comment: @X.Dong Hi, long time no see? You are right though, counter examples are easy to construct once the general idea is in place.

Comment: @Jacquard I decomposed $U$ because I tried to answer your question: can all $U$ such that $U|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|U = |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ be decomposed as $U = \prod_k{U_{{\mathcal N}_k} }$ when $|\psi\rangle$ is defined on a set of connected neighborhoods ${\mathcal N}_k$? The statement on $|\psi\rangle$ being in the kernel of the generator is quite general, but then we have to consider the particular case you are interested in. Btw, forgot to add transition from $U|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|U = |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ to $U|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$. Should I add it anyway?

Comment: @X.Dong: I'm looking for a counterexample concerning a *connected* neighbourhood structure. It's easy to find counterexamples if the neighbourhoods are not connected.

Comment: @udrv: I think that the idea of exploiting the fact that a state is invariant iff it's in the kernel of the generator can be indeed helpful. (The transition from density matrices to vectors it's rather straightforward.)

Comment: Ok. Then in addition to what X.Dong suggested, why not build a basis by exploiting the "local" structure (I assume you'd be looking at a product of "neighborhood bases"), then build a counterexample $G$ in terms of eigenstates orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$. It suffices to choose one eigenstate that makes $G$ non-additive on the neighborhoods.